# HTML комментарий в теле сообщения завершается на > вместо -->

Tags: дефект, markdown

При попытке поместить следующий кусок разметки (комментарий) в тело сообщения, его часть после `>` отображается как текст, хотя не должна:

```
<!-- a > b -->
```

Косяк наблюдается как в превью, так и после публикации.

Разметка полностью:

```
# Пробуем

Пишем что-то до комментария.

<!-- a > b -->

И после комментария.
```

## Пробуем

Пишем что-то до комментария.

b -->

И после комментария.

## Скриншот:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Ну так это же html, вместо `>` надо писать `&gt;`

Comment: @АндрейNOP, это же комментарий. Кстати, в новом редакторе исправлено. По крайней мере в превью.

Comment: Такое надо постить на MSE